# How to recover SSD drive C: that shows empty after installing Windows updates

Tags: windows-8, hard-drive, boot, ssd

I have a Samsung SSD 830 Series drive installed as drive C: on my desktop, with Windows 8 on it. This morning I installed Windows updates, about a dozen of them. (Unfortunately I don't remember what was in the list.) The updates screen showed that updates failed. I decided to reboot and try again...

When computer was booting, it got hung up on the boot screen.

I booted up into recovery console and switched to drive C: and ran the `dir` command to see what files I show on it. (This site doesn't let me post screenshots here, so let me type what I got.)

```
Microsoft Windows [Versoin 6.2.9200]

X:\windows\system32>C:

C:\>dir
 Volume in drive C has no label.
 Volume Serial Number is 4AED-8374

 Directory of C:\

01/03/2014  09:56 PM            0 Recovery.txt
                 1 Files(s)     0 Bytes
                 0 Dir(s)   114,491,392 bytes fee

C:\>
```

The drive is a 256GB `Samsung 830 Series` SSD, that the OS, Windows 8 was installed on. It had about 56GB of free space left on it.

Ding it! Does it mean all my files are gone? Why is it showing that I have no files on it? I haven't run any recovery tools on it yet. Are there any that may recover it?

Answer (score 0):

For security reasons, you may want to work with that hardware in other computer in order to prevent data loss. Make sure you are working with the right disk and the right drive letter all the time.

Check the SMART information of your disk to see if it is healthy. Additionally, you should check if the partitions you had before in that disk are still there.  There are programs to do that in command line, like diskpart. Most likely, you will see two partitions in that disk, one big, C:/, and one small that is created by Windows 8 for some reasons. If you don't see them, try to create a full all sectors backup before doing anything else. If the partitions are OK, try to get the information about their size and left space from the disk managment program you are using. If they difer from what you expect, maybe you need to do a recovery, big or small, if they don't, check the files, they are there, most likely.

Comment: Thanks for the post. (Sorry I don't have enough reputation to upvote it.) Just curious, how do I check the SMART info and other parameters that you suggested?